# TextControl Images/Watermarks

Tags: watermark, txtextcontrol

In version 18 of TextControl (http://www.textcontrol.com) there is supposed to be the ability to add background images/watermarks to the document, however I find that the behavior of the various overloads, etc is not working correctly and that the documentation is rather scarce on examples.  Does any one have a working example of adding watermarks to a Word document through the ServerTextControl object?

This functionality didn't exist in previous versions, so I recognize it's still rather new, I just find it weird that doing something like 
 `tx.Images.Add(draftImage, pageNumber, location, ImageInsertionMode.BelowTheText);`

doesn't actually add the images to the document, but if I use another overload beforehand, it adds both?

I just need a loop along the lines of

```
foreach (TXTextControl.Page page in pages){
    page.Select();
    var location = tx.InputPosition.Location;
    var pageNumber = page.Number;
    tx.Images.Add(draftImage, pageNumber, location, ImageInsertionMode.BelowTheText);
}
```

where location is supposed to be the beginning of the page.

Any help would be appreciated, this should be simple!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a response to this on their forum, it's not a complete solution, but it works for the most part.  Figured I would follow up here, so that anyone who ends up on this page would get the help I wanted.

http://forums.textcontrol.com/showthread.php?325522-Watermarking-Background-Image-on-Saved-Documents-in-X8&p=41815#post41815